# Play 2.1 SSL Configuration

Tags: java, ssl, playframework-2.1

I'm new to Play and in the process of configuring SSL for production. I can successfully run in dev mode with a self signed certificate, but when I try to use a signed certificate the initial client handshake fails and Play generates the following stack trace:

```
play - Error loading HTTPS keystore from conf/keystore.jks
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyManagerFactory not available
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.java:139) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory$$anonfun$sslContext$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:74) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory$$anonfun$sslContext$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:62) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory.sslContext$lzycompute(NettyServer.scala:62) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
```

I'm running Play 2.1.1 and Java 1.7.0_11. I've configured ssl support as follows:

//generate a csr

`keytool -certreq -alias server -keyalg RSA -file server.csr -keystore keystore.jks`

//load root and intermediate certs

```
keytool -import -alias godaddy -keystore keystore.jks -file gd_bundle.crt
```

//load signed cert

```
keytool -import -alias server -keystore keystore.jks -file server.crt
```

//launch play with system parameters to run ssl

```
sudo ../../jars/play-2.1.1/play -Dhttps.port=443 -Dhttps.keyStore="conf/keystore.jks" -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=REDACTED -Dhttps.keyStoreAlgorithm="RSA" run
```

Does anyone know how java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyManagerFactory not available error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `-Dhttps.keyStoreAlgorithm=RSA` from your command. @gma is right, this is the algorithm for the key store, not the key.

I used the following commands to start my play application with a key I generated:

```
keytool -genkey -alias MyKey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.jks
play -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttps.keyStore=keystore.jks -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=password run
```

Then pointed my browser to `https://localhost:9443`

Comment: Thanks, I had success with this too. See my comment in response to @gma.

Answer (score 1):

It is because RSA is not your **keyStoreAlgorithm** but you **Key** algorithm.
Change `-Dhttps.keyStoreAlgorithm="RSA` to `-Dhttps.keyStoreAlgorithm="jks"` as **jks** is the default format for Java keystores.

Comment: When I used jks as the keystore algo I received the same error. I then re-keyed my certificate and launched Play, unsuccessfully, with the https.keyStoreAlgorithm="jks". However, I successfully launched Play by excluding the https.keyStoreAlgorithm parameter.

Comment: I also tried `-Dhttps.keyStoreAlgorithm="jks"` and got the same error as @merritts