# Play Framework 2.1 SSL Configuration

Tags: ssl, playframework-2.1

I've spent the better part of this afternoon trying to figure out how to implement SSL/TLS support directly in the Play Framework 2.1 web server without having to use a front end proxy, to no avail.  I have all of my certificates signed by a CA and I'm told Play 2.1 supports SSL, but am lost on the configuration options to use in `application.conf` to set this up.  There doesn't appear to be a clear answer out there in the documentation.

Couple questions:

1. Do I *HAVE* to convert my `.crt` and `.key` files to a `.jks` file (Java keystore) or can I use them as-is?
2. If I have to import to the Java keystore, can someone provide some insight into how this is done? I have seen a lot of conflicting documentation on this.
3. What are the configuration options in the Play Framework 2.1.x `application.conf` to set this up?

As I stated before, I could not find any clear answers after a couple hours of Googling, so I figured I better ask here. Also, I want to reiterate - I *DO NOT* want to use a front-end web server like Apache for specific reasons, so I am looking *ONLY* to set up SSL/TLS support directly in Play.

EDIT:

I have found this thread: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/play-framework/1326s1ttny/2-1-ssl but I can't get any of it to work still.  Not sure if I'm created the JKS file correctly by combining all of my bundled CRT files AND the private key into a single file then importing and I'm not sure what I should use for the "path to keystore".

Comment: I would say easy way to configure ssl for your server is to do it with nginx and not directly with play

Comment: Yeah, but I was trying to avoid setting up a front end server.

Comment: check this out . I think this answers all your doubts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035690/play-2-1-ssl-configuration