# Play framework 2.2.1 HTTPs fails on connection attempt

Tags: java, https, playframework

I am trying to run play framework 2.2.1 application on HTTPs in dev mode. I use the following command:

```
Development/Play/ssltest$ JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttps.port=9443 play run
```

I got the following, which seems to be OK

```
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[info] play - Listening for HTTPS on port /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9443

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

However, when I try to connect to the app over HTTPS:

```
"https://localhost:9443"
```

The app crash and I go the following stack of exceptions:

```
[error] play - Error loading fake key store
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Subject class type invalid.
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.setSubject(X509CertInfo.java:888) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.set(X509CertInfo.java:415) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
at play.core.server.netty.FakeKeyStore$.createSelfSignedCertificate(FakeKeyStore.scala:71) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.netty.FakeKeyStore$.keyManagerFactory(FakeKeyStore.scala:34) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory$$anonfun$sslContext$2.apply(NettyServer.scala:98) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory$$anonfun$sslContext$2.apply(NettyServer.scala:94) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]

[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ﾎﾫ?BYFￅﾛ￵￣X￶￧ﾣﾇ$￀+￀/ﾞﾜ￀
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:102) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

 [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ﾎﾫ?BYFￅﾛ￵￣X￶￧ﾣﾇ$￀+￀/ﾞﾜ￀
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:102) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

 [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

 [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ￀
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:102) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ￀
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:102) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems play on my machine fail to generate itself a self signed certificate. If I used my own self signed certificate it works with no problem.

```
keytool -genkey -alias MyKey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.jks
play -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttps.keyStore=keystore.jks -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=password run
```

I got the answer from this [post] ([Play 2.1 SSL Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035690/play-2-1-ssl-configuration))

Comment: Nice solution but outdated. The play framework deprecated 'play' command. Use 'activator' instead.

Comment: @Nativ correct the play command is deprecated, however, you only need to replace it with activator and the rest of the command will work for new version of the play framework

Answer (score 26):

The issue is discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/ip6cT70VjZ4/I5cHNv0rOWkJ

The problem is sending https requests
to localhost.
The solutions are:

1. the easy way: keep localhost url, but replace https with http
2. the hard way:
   set up correct domain name mapping by messing around with /etc/hosts
   and configure ssl to run on your localhost

Comment: In addition to https, it could also be a port scanner, which opens a connection to this port and sends random data to check what works.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try 
    `https://localhost:9443` 
(note the colon instead of slash before the 9443)

Comment: It is a typo in my question.

Comment: This helped me — I accidentally connected to port `:9000` instead as usual, and then I got the error in this question. And now I noticed my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a path to a certificate/keystore that you have provided is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem.

If you are using `ssl`, try deleting `conf/generated.keystore`, restart server (with `-Dhttps.port=9443` option). New certificate will be automatically created and problem is resolved