# Play Framework serve HTTPS content

Tags: https, playframework

I am a newbie at play, and I am trying at least to use HTTPS on a login and sign up pages in order to have more security on sensitive user data.
I have a range of questions regarding this:

1. I have configured my play application to use https on the application.conf file with the https.port property. However in my development environment I cant seem to start the server with https capability unless I use the command: `play -Dhttps.port=<port>`
   Why does this happen? I would think that I could use a dev.conf (right now is the application.conf) file in order to do this. Can't I start the server in dev mode while using this kind of settings specified on the configuration file?
2. Although I start the server with https capabilities, what is the correct way to use https on play? I already created a java key store that I use, and tried to redirect (from a controller) requests to a https url using `redirect(securedIndexCall.absoluteURL(request, secure))`. But it does not seem to work at least on my dev enviroment (localhost). The logs specify exceptions like:

   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text`
   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: M¥å/=<junk characters continue>`
3. Should I use https on the whole application, or just securing the login and sign up requests is sufficient?

I feel the official documentation provided is rather insufficient and I am at a loss here trying to figure out how I should do this.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Those should probably be 3 questions, not one. I'm afraid that this question is too broad. Also, I suggest you use a front-end server for HTTP e.g. [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Fernando, I think it's easier to set up a front end web server. In my case I used Lighttpd and it was fairly straightforward to set up. I'd recommend:

1. Configure Lighttpd as per these instructions (at this stage, don't worry about HTTPS just get HTTP working): http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/HTTPServer
2. Then configure HTTPS in Lighttpd: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToSimpleSSL. If you intend on buying an SSL certificate then there will be a few more options to set (e.g. intermediate certificate). The following page has more information: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_SSL

---

Answers to your main questions:

**1) Enabling HTTPS in Play**

Yes, you have to explicitly say you want to use HTTPS when starting up
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ConfiguringHttps

**2) The "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" error message**

There might be an issue with the keystore. This SO article seems to discuss in more detail: [Play framework 2.2.1 HTTPs fails on connection attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667254/play-framework-2-2-1-https-fails-on-connection-attempt)

**3) SSL for login page or whole app**

Personally, I would go for the whole app. If you're taking the time to set up HTTPS I think you might as well cover the whole site. I guess there are slight performance overheads in running HTTPS but realistically it's not something you'd notice.

Comment: The reason why I want play to use HTTPS directly is because the app will be deployed in a cloud (Heroku) and I dont know if I have the possibility of setting up a frond end web server.

Comment: I've never tried it but I reckon this is something Heroku will deal with when you buy the SSL add on (https://addons.heroku.com/ssl). I don't think your app will need to be aware of SSL. They probably have a  similar setup to the one I described for load balancing (i.e. a web server which directs requests to the instances of your app).

Comment: I found out why those exceptions were being thrown. I though that in dev mode play read the https configurations from application.conf. However this is not true. The fact was those excpetions were caused because play did not have access to the keystore. I have to pass all needed parameters in order to work properly: `play debug -Dhttps.port=<httpsport> -Dhttps.keyStore=<keystore> -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=<keystorepassword>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a front end server for HTTPS, and use HTTPS for the whole application.

Please see [Setting up a front end HTTP server](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/HTTPServer) and see the commented out nginx settings.